# Whatsapp message breaks after hash

Tags: hash, whatsapp

I'm trying to send message by my button href value as :

```
whatsapp://send?text=textmessage+!favourite+#knowledge+To+know+more
```

But my message when whatsapp opens is getting break at hash(#).
Thus receiving message like "textmessage !favourite" (without quotes)

Please help with the solution

Answer (score 0):

May be do you need to encode that url with **encodeURIComponent**.

For example, I use JavaScript for that:

```
var myMessage = "textmessage!favourite#knowledge...";
var messageToWhatsApp = encodeURIComponent(myMessage);
var url = "whatsapp://send?text=" + messageToWhatsApp;
```

And bind with your button with the event **onClick** or with jQuery.